# Add data to returned model sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I have a sequelize model object that is working like expected.

```
const part = sequalize.define("part", {
        id: {type:Sequalize.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true},
        part_number: {type : Sequalize.STRING(12), unique: true, allowNull: false},
        description: {type : Sequalize.STRING(255), allowNull: false}, true}
    })
```

But I want to run an additional function when this model is called for example in a query.

I have this function now:

```
part.prototype.getTotalStock = function () {
        let _this = this;
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            part.findOne({
                where: {id: _this.id},
                include: [{
                    model: sequalize.models.location,
                }]
            }).then(result => {
                if (result) {
                    var totalStock = 0;
                    let stockOnLocation = result.dataValues.locations

                    stockOnLocation.forEach(function (entry) {
                        totalStock += entry.stock.amount
                    });

                    _this.setDataValue('totalStock', totalStock);

                    return resolve(_this)
                } else {
                    return resolve(0)
                }
            }).catch(err => {
                return reject(err)
            });
        })
    }
```

What i'm doing is that I do a query so I have 1 part object. After that I can call:

queryResult.getTotalStock().then(result => {
  //data here in result
})

That is working, its retrieving the stock, calculating it, and it is adding the data to self. Now my question, is it possible to append the result of getTotalStock automatically when the model is being used? So that I don't have to call getTotalStock on the returned object?